# Problem about central limit theorem related to finding probability of a R.V similar to binomial

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

In a city there is 1000 houses. We know that each house has 1/2 chance to not have any mouse. (So with 1/2 chance, it has 1 or more mice). A person gets 1$ for every ten mice he catches.

a) Find the probability that after checking all of the houses, he gets more than 2$.

b) If we denote average mice he catches in a house by $M$, How many houses he should search such that $P(0.3\leq M \leq 0.7)\geq0.9$

At first I thought we have a binomial distribution but I found out that we don't know what is the distribution exactly because we want number of mouses and not if they exist or not. The question is actually from a quiz designed for central limit theorem but we don't know average nor the variance of distribution to use CLT.

What should I do?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If he has a probability $1/2$ zero mice and a probability of $1/2$ of one million mice then he has $1-1/2^{1000}$ chance of getting more than \$2. If instead he has a $1/2$ probability of catching exactly one mouse, then it is something smaller than this: just the probability of getting more than $20$ heads in a $1000$ coinflips which is still very close to one but not nearly as close as the first example. Something seems very off here.

Comment: I was confused by the second one cause I thought $M$ was somehow related to the distribution of mice that would be found at a given house. Reading a little closer this does seem like a routine CLT problem... you just need to specify that there is a $1/2$ chance of *exactly* one mouse, rather than just "one or more" which as I indicated above, makes the problem underdetermined.

Comment: Indeed, the probability distribution of the number of mice found in a random house should be given.